# How to use query function to fix slow performance laravel datatable?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatable

I would like to use the query function, because I have a slow performance in laravel datatable. I have this select:

```
$audits = \OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit::select(
            'audits.id',
            'audits.user_type',
            'audits.user_id',
            'audits.event',
            'audits.auditable_id',
            'audits.auditable_type',
            'audits.old_values',
            'audits.new_values',
            'audits.created_at',
            'users.login'
        )
        ->join('users','users.id','audits.user_id');
```

and I tried to use the query function this way:

```
$audits = \OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit::query()->select(
            'audits.id',
            'audits.user_type',
            'audits.user_id',
            'audits.event',
            'audits.auditable_id',
            'audits.auditable_type',
            'audits.old_values',
            'audits.new_values',
            'audits.created_at',
            'users.login'
        )
        ->join('users','users.id','audits.user_id');
```

But is not working the code above. 
I thought to use Laravel Pagination, however in the project that I work has datatables in so many tables and I want to keep the same standard. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding of what `query()` does. Simply put **it does nothing differently** and it will **not** help you with any optimization for your queries.

---

#### Model::select(args)

When you do `Model::select('col1', 'col2')`, this is what happens:

1. There is no `Model::select` public static function, so `__callStatic(method: 'select', parameters: ['col1', 'col2'])` gets called instead.
2. All `__callStatic` does in `Model` is try to call a public function `method` passing in `parameters`.

```php
# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

3. There is no `Model::select` public function, so `__call(method: 'select', parameters: ['col1', 'col2'])` gets called instead.
4. All `__call` does is forward the call to the object returned from the public function `Model::newQuery`. So, `(new Model)->newQuery()->select(['col1', 'col2'])`

```php
# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }

    if ($resolver = ($this->relationResolver(static::class, $method))) {
        return $resolver($this);
    }

    return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters);
}
```

To summarize, when you do `Model::select(args)`, it's the same as doing `(new Model)->newQuery()->select(args)`.

#### Model::query()->select(args)

This is the source code for the Model::query public static function.

```php
public static function query()
{
     return (new static)->newQuery();
}
```

As you can see, it's the same.

---

The only "optimization" that comes out of using `query()` is making the call stack shorter.

`Model::select()`

- calls `__callStatic`
- calls `__call`
- calls `forwardCallTo`
- calls `newQuery`

`Model::query()->select()`

- calls `newQuery`

There are still a few extra steps that happen between `newQuery` and `select`, but they are the same.

---

As for possible optimizations:

1. Creating an index on `audits` 's `user_id` column
2. Pagination
3. Lazily loading the results (cursor, lazy)

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#cursors
- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#chunking-using-lazy-collections

4. Loading the data through ajax

- https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax